# Visual Studio 2022 Errors showing in Output tab, Error list tab is blank

Tags: visual-studio

This was working until today.

The errors on build are not showing in the error list, I have the error list set as Build + IntelliSense.  The build error is showing in the output window.

This started yesterday.

I have tried:

- Clean solution.
- Delete vs folder.
- Restart Visual studio
- Delete obj and bin folders

Still get same results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I had hit upvote on this question because my team has the same problem, but i think this is probably better suited as feedback in the MS developer community, as its unlikely this is a "answerable" question from a stackoverflow perspective.

Comment: @Community What's unclear for you in this question is unclear to me, least to say.

Comment: @Charles S: Are you targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 or earlier? This seems to be a known issue that Microsoft does not intend to fix, because it does not show up in .NET 5 or later. See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/42573
I have the same problem. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: I had a similar problem and fixed it by setting "Run background code analysis" and "Show compiler errors and warnings" to "Entire solution".

Answer (score 2):

I've been seeing this issue too (assuming I read it right).

**Symptoms:**

- When running a full Rebuild, errors are encountered, and displayed in the Build Output window.
- The Error List shows no errors or warnings. (0 Errors, 0 Warnings, x Messages)
- None of the Messages are actually warnings/errors mis-categorized.
- Selecting an appropriate code file shows the errors/warnings underlined properly.
- When viewing the code file, the error block (next to the zoom in the file footer) shows the correct details for errors.
- Clicking on the error block opens the Error List, however none of the entries are visible.

**Current workaround:**

- Unlike the OP, a restart (and sometimes needing a Rebuild too) will resolve the issue for me ... for a while.

**Supposition:**

It seems like at some point, the VS IDE stops updating the Error List and clears it, and will not add new errors or warnings to it.  I haven't tracked the 'messages' to know if that's also affected, but until I restart, the Error List will show zero errors or warnings regardless of the actual situation.